# How to call a Function in UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to call below mentioned function ***onSaveInputValue*** into the ***useEffect*** so that, my component can have passed ***value*** in ***childInputValue*** hook whenever the page gets loaded.

```
    const onSaveInputValue = (value) => {
        setChildInputValue(value);
        console.log(childInputValue);
      };
```

I have tried to do so but couldn't do it. Please guide me.

In case if you like to see the full code of components then it is mentioned as below.

**Parent  Component:-**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [childInputValue, setChildInputValue] = useState();
  // useEffect(() => {});
    const onSaveInputValue = (value) => {
    setChildInputValue(value);
    console.log("childVInputValue",value)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <p>{childInputValue}</p>

      {/* We pass function to the child component. */}
      <Child onSaveInputValue={onSaveInputValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

**Child Component:-**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function Child(props) {
  const [baseImage, setBaseImage] = useState("");

  const uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const base64 = await convertBase64(file);
    setBaseImage(base64);
    props.onSaveInputValue(baseImage);
  };

  const convertBase64 = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

      fileReader.onload = () => {
        resolve(fileReader.result);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  };


  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("useeeffect",baseImage)
  })

  return (
    <div >
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          uploadImage(e);
        }}
      />
      <br></br>
      <img src={baseImage} height="200px" />
      <hr/>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: `useEffect(() => { onSaveInputValue("initial value"); }, []);`

Comment: Just pass your initial state to `useState()`, don't even need to call this function.

Comment: Sir, i tried to do the same then got the error.  'onSaveInputValue' & 'value' is not defined

Comment: `useState(() => fetchInitialValue())`, you do not need to call `useEffect`

Comment: @SamriddhaBajpai — `value` *is* undefined because you never define it. I have no idea what you expect it to be.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove a lot of stuff

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = () => {
  const [childInputValue, setChildInputValue] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <p>{childInputValue}</p>

      {/* We pass function to the child component. */}
      <Child onSaveInputValue={setChildInputValue} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

Comment: Here, Error will come as  'onSaveInputValue' is not defined beacuse it isn't.

Comment: You are right, I didn't change the callback name.

If the error now persists, it has to be with Child.